# Htaccess: changes root and doesn't find files

Tags: php, .htaccess, pretty-urls

I have a htaccess file that I am try to make a rewrite but it causes me multiple problems. First here is my htacess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ index.php?category=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&itemId=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}

RewriteRule ^login$ login.php?category=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

The first problem is that when I make a request like "mysite/foo/bar/", it does rewrite the query string in category and itemId but it also changes the base directory for my css files and Js files to /foo/bar/design/css/style.css

The second problem is that I have a few path like "login/","register/","users/", and when I try to load the corresponding file, it says:

```
The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server.
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First change your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&itemId=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php?category=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: for example mysite.com/foo/bar/ just says that the request url not found

Comment: Is `/foo/bar` a real directory?

Comment: In that case it will be internally rewritten to `index.php?category=foo&itemId=bar`